# What's #abc called in component?

Tags: angular

`<app-abc #abc></app-abc>`

What's #abc called?
How do we refer to #abc inside parent component?

Comment: A template reference variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's a way to refer HTML element in your component. Here is the way to refer to #abc inside parent component:

```
import {ViewChild, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';

export class YourClass {
    // Reference firstNameInput variable inside Component
    @ViewChild('abc') nameInputRef: ElementRef;
}
```

[Working with Angular 5 Template Reference Variables](https://itnext.io/working-with-angular-5-template-reference-variable-e5aa59fb9af)

Answer (score 0):

You refer to #abc in your component like this:

```
export class MyApp {
    @ViewChild('abc') abcElement;
}
```