# What does # in angular html mean?

Tags: angular

This might be a silly question but what does a `#` mean when it is directly inside a html element in angular? For example: `div #messagesContainer class="myClass"></div>`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45250259/what-is-auto-attribute-here-and-why-it-is-required/45251464#45251464

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's #abc called in component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60482249/whats-abc-called-in-component)

Answer (score 2):

This feature is called template reference variables.
For more information you can read this [Angular - Template reference variables](https://angular.io/guide/template-reference-variables)